# Can I use the mono ammonium phosphate found in fire extinguishers to make crystals?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I recently opened up a old decompressed fire extinguisher out of curiosity. After some research I discovered that the dry powder inside, mono ammonium phosphate, can be used to make beautiful crystals. However, I found this powder to be extremely hydrophobic and could never get its dissolve in water at all. I mean this stuff is amazingly hydrophobic. Its fun to see how it reacts in water. But why cant it dissolve and what kind of preparation of mono ammonium phosphate will dissolve and become crystals?

Comment: I think you aren't using the word "hydrophobic" properly

Comment: Sprinkle it with alcohol.

Comment: Fire extinguisher powder can be made hydrophobic by additives like stearates or silicones. However this is rather done with sodium/potassium hydrogencarbonate, potassium sulphate, or sodium/potassium chloride powders (BC class). For monoammonium and ammonium phosphate powders (ABC class) I wouldn't expect them to be hydrophobic. Are you sure about the chemical composition?

Answer (score 0):

If you google for MAP, you'll find out that it is quite soluble in water, ranging from [370](https://www.ipni.net/publication/nss.nsf/0/2F200FA9C8C946F0852579AF00762904/$FILE/NSS-09%20Monoammonium%20Phosphate.pdf) to 401 g/litre of H2O at temperatures around 25 C. Thus, what you report contradicts literature data on MAP's solubility. So, maybe the powder you found is not MAP, it's something else (CaCO3 comes to my mind, because it is insoluble in water and yields CO2 when heated, but I may be wrong).

Comment: sanity check, does not react to vinegar -> not carbonate. Separately, litmus paper shows acidic, as expected for ammonium phosphate and sulfate

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_dry_chemical "specially fluidized and siliconized monoammonium phosphate powder" - it's the anticaking agents that make it hydrophobic. Ammonium salts being hygroscopic on their own, i figure forming a lump inside extinguisher is no good